# How to compute loss for every data point in Keras?

Tags: keras, tensorflow2.0

I use Tensorflow 2.0 and Keras to train a model. I do the following to load a pre-trained model which I then use for inference:

```
checkpoint_dir = "./"
x_test = np.random.normal(n_points, n_features)
model = tf.keras.models.load_model(checkpoint_dir)
predictions = model.predict(x_test)
```

I would like to know if I can get the loss for every data point as well? Is it possible to do something like

```
loss = model.compute_loss(x_test, y_test)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just take a loss function from the backend and use it.

Example - if eager mode is on:

```
losses = tf.keras.backend.categorical_crossentropy(true_data, pred_data)
```

Example - if eager mode is off:

```
def loss_calc(x):
    return backend.categorical_crossentropy(x[0], x[1])

trueIn = Input(shape_of_the_targets)
predIn = Input(shape_of_the_targets)
out = Lambda(loss_calc)([trueIn, predIn])

loss_model = Model([trueIn, predIn], out)

losses = loss_model.predict([true_data, pred_data])
```

Answer (score -1):

You can *evaluate* the model using

```
model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)
```

Evaluate Returns the loss value & metrics values for the model in test mode. (https://keras.io/models/model/)

Comment: But this is the overall evaluation, not for every data point.

Comment: I usually do a list comprehension, but it is extremely slow and I'm looking for a better way:
[tf.keras.backend.categorical_crossentropy(x, y).numpy() for x, y in zip(true_data, pred_data)]